# Latency measurement

Tags: perl

I would like to measure the time taken to download a picture form the web server. I would like to use Perl, python or PHP but preferbaly Perl. The time to be in ms. I would to run the script from HTML.

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Perl cannot run in the browser if that is what you are refering to when you say "From the HTML".

I suggest you look into the [onload event in Javascript.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You would run the script from HTML? You mean you'd invoke some kind of CGI?

Your "issue" should be pretty straight forward in any programming language, that has some kind of blocking HTTP GET request method; For example in Perl:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday tv_interval/;

my $b = [gettimeofday];
get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565423/latency-measurement");

print "Took me: ",  tv_interval($b), "\n";
```

But this doesn't represent how long it took to download the file. It only shows how long this specific implementation of a GET request (via LWP::Simple) took. If you really want the time only for the request you'll have to dig a lot deeper. (Although I doubt that it makes great difference....)

Comment: thanks sebastian.. the time is it in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: I don't know, but how else would you run Perl "from the HTML"? ;-)